# Giving char* to std::string for management (to eventually free memory)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to use a library function that allocates a bit of memory for a generated string and returns a `char*`, with the expectation that the caller eventually free the memory with `free()`.

```
// Example declaration of the library function:
char* foo();
// ...
// Example usage:
auto foo_str = foo();
// ...
free(foo_str);
```

Is it possible to construct a `std::string` from this pointer, passing ownership of the memory to the string object so it will be freed when the string is destructed? I know I could implement my own wrapper that would give this RAII behavior, but I'm guessing this wheel has already been invented once.

Comment: How about creating a `std::unique_ptr` from your raw pointer? Or is C++11 not an option?

Comment: `unique_ptr` does not use `free()`.   It will use some form of operator delete.

Comment: @Peter `unique_ptr` can delete however you want it to delete.

Comment: @Michael Of course `unique_ptr`! I failed by not considering that. Of course C++11 is an option, I tagged the question with it :)

Comment: Ah, a -1 over a month after asking the question. I wish downvotes required comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot use `string` for such a thing. `string` always owns its buffer, and will allocate and deallocate its own. You can't *transfer* ownership into a `string`. I don't even know if there's a proposal for such a thing.

There *is* a container that you can transfer ownership into though: [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
struct free_deleter {
    void operator()(void* p) {
        free(p);
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<char, free_deleter> foo_str = foo();
```

Comment: I didn't even consider `unique_ptr`, which is the obvious solution. +1 for showing how to replace the deleter.

Comment: So, if my own C++ function is supposed to return `std::string` -- with the content returned by a C-function (such as `asprintf`), _the only_ option is to _copy_ that memory by constructing the new `string`-object, eh? What a waste... Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a std::string from the **char*** pointer, but the std::string will allocate the char array itself. You will still need to free the char* returned by your library :

```
char* c = foo();
std::string foo_str( c );
free( c );
```

You can also create a function that ensure the deletion of the char* and return a std::string :

```
std::string char_to_string_with_free( const char* c )
{
    std::string str( c );
    free( c );
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `return std::move( str );// std::move if using C++11` <-- AFAIK, adding `std::move` here can prevent Return Value Optimization, thereby leading to less efficient code.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I ajusted the answer

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK std::string hasn't such constructor, that takes ownership of `char*`. Anyway its a bad idea to free memory outside of library, where it was allocated (if we speak about shared object or DLL).

Comment: The documentation of the library explicitly says that the pointer must be freed.

Comment: Usually in such situation library provides a function to free memory allocated in it.

Comment: @ElohimMeth, `asprintf` is a good -- if underappreciated -- example of a function, that does not...